# Is it possible to do arithmetic with methods in Objective-C?

Tags: objective-c, math, methods, addition

In C# I can add getters `anIntVariable = someMethod1() + someMethod2()...` but in Objective-C, I a get a warning, "Implicit Declaration of function 'someMethod1'is invalid in c99. What is the equivalent way to do arithmetic with methods? Thanks.

Comment: Maybe you shouldn't call functions that haven't been declared...

Comment: Yea, I'm kinda new in Objective-C, so I'm not familiar with the methods. I have a text book on Objective-C but it doesn't show any examples so I just thought to ask if its possible.

Comment: Well, it is possible, but in your case you are calling some method which is not declared and your compiler complains. Try using some real functions -- you'll see that it works.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do this in Objective C.

```
NSInteger myNumber = [self method1] + [self method2]; // myNumber is 3
```

Where method1 & method2 might be implemented like:

```
- (NSInteger)method1 {
     return 1;
}

- (NSInteger)method2 {
     return 2;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

This is pretty basic stuff; recommend you take a moment to read more about Obj-C syntax if you're interested in picking up the language.

This is the equiv of your example.

```
NSInteger anIntVariable = [self someMethod1] + [self someMethod2];
```

If "someMethod1" is the getter for a "property", you may also be able to write "self.method1" to get the value of that property.

Objective-C is a fun language.  I think you'll love it if you give it a chance.

Good luck.

Comment: Thank you too! I'll do my best haha. You guys are great!